# Single Double quotes in password not working

Tags: php

I'm tring to connect with one of my SFTP server using php sftp connection functions but password has single+double quotes which doesnt allow me to connect to server.

```
$sftp = new SFTPConnection("sftp.clientname.com", 22);
$connection = $sftp->login("client_name", "*agjTN2&'u`"K"h[7+?");
```

I have tried with adding mysql_real_escape_string function to password but not worked for me

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php You need to escape the internal `"`s.

Comment: Are you sure that this code does not throw a syntax error? And why do you want to escape a string that is not meant to be used in a database context by a MySQL function?

Comment: precede the single and double quotes with \

Comment: ```$pass = "*agjTN2&'u`\"K\"h[7+?"; $sftp->login("client_name", $pass);```

Answer (score 3):

You can escape the double quotes with back slash `\` as

```
<?php
    echo "*agjTN2&'u`\"K\"h[7+?";
?>
```

In Your case:

```
$sftp = new SFTPConnection("sftp.clientname.com", 22);
$connection = $sftp->login("client_name", "*agjTN2&'u`\"K\"h[7+?");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the rule :

If your string is between **"__test__"** (double quote) preced double quote inside string with backslash \  , single quote don't need to be preceded by backslash .

```
$password = "*agjTN'2&u\"K\"h[7+?";
echo $password; // output : *agjTN'2&u"K"h[7+?
```

If your string is between **'__test__'** (single quote) , do the inverse .

```
$password = '*agjTN\'2&u"K"h[7+?';
echo $password; // output : *agjTN'2&u"K"h[7+?
```